# Prove via induction that the coin set {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,k$} is canonical

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, induction

Canonical - [Greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) always yields the optimal solution.

**My Thinking**

*Base Case:*

Consider the set {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,k$} where we have $k=0$, then we get the set {$1$}

This is clearly canonical.

*Hypothesis:*

Suppose for some $s$, we have that {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,s$} is canonical.

WTS: {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,s+1$} is also canonical.

*Step:*

I don't really know how to use the hypothesis to prove this. How can I use the fact that {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,s$} is canonical to prove that {$c^i:c\ge 1,i=0,...,s+1$} is also canonical?

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical"?

Comment: @martycohen The problem author mentions this right at the start, but more precisely: A coin system $\$$ is said to be *canonical* if the greedy representation of $x$ under $\$$ has the same size as the optimal representation of $x$ under $\$$ for all possible values $x$.

Comment: Thanks. I somehow misread that first line.